# Running an older iOS version in the iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, ios4

I want to test my application on older iOS versions. I am using weak linking for new frameworks and branches in the code for different OS version. But after some complaints from users running iOS 3.1.2, I need to do some testing myself. I don't have a separate iPhone for every iOS version.

So, how can I run an older version of iOS in the iPhone simulator?

That's a really basic question and there might be a duplicate somewhere, but I wasn't able to find it. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can download (or have a backup of) the older SDK that relates to the older OS you want to run on, I believe the general advice is to install the other SDK to a different path (say, *Developer/olderSDK*  and this way you can have both SDK's (and simulators) installed side by side.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea where to download it?

Comment: hmm, this hosed my SDK 4 after install. Only able to build using up to 3.2 now.

This is actually OK for me, as I have an iOS 4 device and so only need v3 testing, but for others it may not be desired.